# Spring Boot Single Page Application Routing on any URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

I am trying to accomplish the following (if possible).

I have a single page application at `localhost:8080` and everything currently lands on `localhost:8080/` even if a user enters: `localhost:8080/signIn`

It does client side routing so that after you land on `localhost:8080/` you can click a button and it takes you to `localhost:8080/signIn`

Is there a way using springboot to allow whatever the user passes in without having it redirect automatically to `localhost:8080/` (all the while returning the single page - index.html)?

Thanks!

Comment: So you need any request on your backend to be redirected to localhost:8080/ ? Always? You don't have any functionality in your spring boot application on other url's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AnythingController{

    @RequestMapping(value="**",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAnything(){
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does capture all incoming requests. I think I have a setting somewhere which redirects everything to `/` so even if they land on `localhost:8080/signIn` it is returning my code in the RequestMapping but there is a 302 redirect to `/` as well which is not what I want.

Comment: Figured it out. I had a spring security context and so when a user was not logged in it would 302 redirect to `/` instead of `signIn` 

Your code works perfectly. Thanks.