# Configure Spring Framework 5.3+, Spring Boot 2.3+ Routing for SPA frontend

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, routes, single-page-application

I have a simple frontend application made using Angular. All routings are handled by Angular so I want Spring boot to forward all page traffics  to `"/"` so angular routing can handle them.

There are already some known answers in stackoverflow. They are:

- [spring-boot-single-page-application-routing-on-any-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996333/spring-boot-single-page-application-routing-on-any-url/52996633)
- [configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769200/configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend)
- [spring-boot-with-redirecting-with-single-page-angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913753/spring-boot-with-redirecting-with-single-page-angular2/43921334)

But none of them work anymore because from [Spring Framework 5.3 and onwards](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc) `AntPathMatcher` has been replaced with `PathPattern`. `PathPattern` is compatible with `AntPathMatcher` syntax except for the following:

> Support for "**" for multi-segment matching is only allowed at the end
> of a pattern. This helps to eliminate most causes of ambiguity when
> choosing the closest match for a given request.

So this won't work anymore:

```java
  // Match everything without a suffix (so not a static resource)
  @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^.]*}")
  public String redirectAngularRoutes() {
    return "forward:/";
  }
```

So what is the best approach now starting with Spring Framework 5.3?

Do we specify each angular routing and `forward` them to `"/"` like below or there are other alternatives?

```java
  @RequestMapping({ "/help/**","/view/**","/admin/**" })
  public String redirectAngularRoutes() {
    return "forward:/";
  }
```

Comment: I would imagine that you would serve your application in whatever way and just let angular handle any routing within pages of the application. If you serve an app with an actual route in the url I would imagine angular would handle it once it initializes, so it should just be a matter of serving the application to the user.

When it comes to api calls they can be to anything (typical REST endpoint calls).

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this :(

Comment: Did you find anything, or did you specify every angular routing? I'm also looking for a solution to this right now

Comment: no update on this from Spring boot. I specify every routing like the 2nd example in the post. @student0495

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the [path matching strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.content-negotiation) to use the ant path matcher in your application.yml

```
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

There is currently no deprecation warning on the Ant Path Matcher but it seems possible it could be removed in the future.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0+ recommend using the `PathPatternParser` as it provides better performance. So your solution is not applicable . read the spring blog: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

Comment: I have the same problem as described in the question, and even though I have set the matching-strategy to be ant_path_matcher it seems it's ignoring/overriding it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach buried in some obscure part of the internet a little while back but I haven't managed to retrace my steps to give credit where it is due. Apologies to the original author.

In any case, this is the solution that was presented and it seems to be working ok for now.

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse


class AngularRoutingFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {


    override fun doFilterInternal(
            request: HttpServletRequest,
            response: HttpServletResponse,
            filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {

        val mode = request.getHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode")

        when (mode) {
            "navigate" -> {
                val rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/")
                rd.forward(request, response)
            }
            else -> filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        }

    }


}
```

This approach has a downside in that it relies on the client setting the correct header. I've found that when running Cypress tests that wasn't happening correctly and I had to override the cy.visit command like so...

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
    originalFn(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate'
            },
            ...options
        }
    )
})
```